# Need to change cookies for every request in loop in POstman

Tags: postman

I have a request and want to run for different data from csv file and at same time I want to change cookies for every request
I have added this in my prescript

```
cookieJar.unset("https://www.website.com/" , 'XX');
cookieJar.set("https://www.website.com/",{name:'XX',value:data.XX,httpOnly: true, domain:"https://www.website.com/"},(error, cookies)=> {console.log("error"+error) });
```

I am not getting any error however cookies are not getting set in cookie manager and cant see it in request header as well. I have also added my domain in allowlist .Please help.

Comment: Can you make a public version of that request with another domain like postman-echo or example.com and share here?

Comment: I got a solution instead of doing programmatically  I added extra cookie in headers and it helped me to solve my problem